# how to use guardianproject's android ffmpeg library?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

First, this is my first time "playing" with ffmpeg, so please bear with me.

Generally, i dont understand ffmpeg even a little bit. So i did lot, lot of researches (and also trial & error) and i finally found [this](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg) project and its [library](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java)

So **i was successfully created the ffmpeg and sox binary file**, and i **put it in the raw** folder at the **library project** (from the link i shared).

Now, i want to use the library for my project, but i still cant do it. I tried to use some methods in the `FfmpegController` like `combineAudioAndVideo` and more but its not working (yet).

I dont post the error here since i still do my trial&errors (and the error change regularly) but im getting tired now.

**EDIT**

This is what i did :

```
private FfmpegController ffController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File file = new File(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/" + R.raw.test).getPath());
        try {
            ffController = new FfmpegController(this, file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MediaDesc desc = ffController.combineAudioAndVideo(R.raw.test, R.raw.musictest, "test.mp4", null);
    }
```

The `combineAudioAndVideo` always error because wrong parameters. It needs `MediaDesc` but i dont know how to do it.

**I will be very happy if you can share your working code if you have done the ffmpeg processing with this library.**

Comment: I agree that it is a pain first to understand how to do this and then more pain actually doing it. There is lots of guidance out there, but it is not very helpful for the beginers.

Comment: LOL :D what should i do? @@